# How can i bring this element to the front? (not z-index)

Tags: css, image, navbar, hidden

The logo element on the website:

puerteaspecialists.co.uk

was originally at the front. I didnt even update anything and one day i check the site and now the top 3rd is hidden behind the nav bar.

Ive tried z - index and have kinda worked out why this isnt working, but also havnt actually found the solution.

Is there a way to bring this to the front or anyway to show the full image via css?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to remove the solid background of the uppermost navigation bar...

```
 .top_nav_out {
     background-color: transparent;
     border: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that class name *.top_nav_out* in your top navigation block applies a high z-index which causes the top-most nav block to overlap the lower navigation block (*.top_nav*) which hides your logo partially.

remove property:

```
z-index
```

from class:

```
.top_nav_out
```

and your logo will be displayed in full.

From what I have seen, the *z-index* property is redundant anyway in that class (layout stayed in good shape after removing it)

Hope it helps a bit!